# Keep just single instance for view per page for all user sessions

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I don't want/need to save separate views for different user sessions, for a single page, as I'm never modifying the pages programmatically. The view is always built based on what's specified in the xhtml files. So view is always the same for a page for all users, so why should I store it as separate view instance for each user & waste my server resources & degrade performance (in building/restoring maintaining view instances while processing each request) for no gains at all.

I'm wondering how to tell JSF to just maintain single instance per page for view. How do I configure JSF to do that ?

Comment: you have a valid requirement but perhaps, you need to vote up & (unfortunately) wait for this issue to get resolved:- http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1055

Comment: also see (if using myfaces implementation) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3465

Comment: [This article](http://industrieit.com/blog/2011/11/stateless-jsf-high-performance-zero-per-request-memory-overhead/) may be on to something.

Comment: I have nothing directly related, but this would probably be to some use for you:

https://showcase-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/showcase/components/cache.xhtml